# Ionic 2 how to create shortcut on homescreen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm developping a ionic 2 app and build and package it with ionic service. But when I install apk on my smartphone there is not shortcut on homescreen. How to make shortcut on homescreen?

Comment: How are you installing the APK?

Comment: On Android device

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the apk from the store, it will create the shortcut but if you installed it with *ionic cordova run android* or *adb install -r appName.apk* it won't create the shortcut, so you  will have to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks. I understand